# Cell colony survival mapping in a particular spatial pattern

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mapping, bioinformatics, spatial

I am attempting to spatially map the cell survival in a given scanned image of a cell flask. Quick background: the cells have received a high dose of irradiation (protons/X-rays) delivered through a grid so that some regions are covered from the irradiation, whereas other regions are not. After scanning such cell colonies, the images are then fed into a segmentation algorithm (in which I have developed using Matlab), centroid coordinates (c_i = (x_i,y_i)) of each detected viable colony are provided.

I have done this type of assessment for grid ‘stripes’, where I have counted colonies within a band along a single dimension (x) and tested for different band widths Δx (as shown in the left figure below). However, my issue is for grid ‘holes’ (see right figure below) – how can I perform the same type of assessment for cell colony survival in two dimensions (x and y) given the centroid coordinates? Do I have to “think” radially?

Thank you in advance for any guidance or help to this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right direction. In the left side image the variation is along x-axis and you are using a new axis for plating efficiency (y-axis).

Similarly, for grid - you will have to introduce a new axis : z axis. Suppose your image I is 500x500 and each grid-cell is 50x50. So you will create a 10x10 grid G where each cell of G is count of centroids in one 50x50 grid cell of I.

Since visualizing a 3-D chart is difficult, people use images, where the value of z-axis is the intensity in image or the grayscale value of a grayscale image. Make sure to normalize your z-axis values on [0,1] or [0,255] range for using images as your visualization tool.